# Fill in missing monthly data with an SQLAlchemy query

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a database table which lists times when a game was played. I am now querying this table to gather data for displaying in a graph, as to get a nice overview of the number of games played per month over the past year.

The following worked perfectly, until covid-19 lockdowns came upon us, and we started seeing months with zero games. :-/

```
data_db = list(                                                             
      games.group_by("year")                                                  
      .group_by("month")                                                      
      .order_by(desc("year"))                                                 
      .order_by(desc("month"))                                                
      .limit(12)                                                              
      .values(                                                                
          func.extract("year", Game.created).label("year"),                   
          func.extract("month", Game.created).label("month"),                 
          func.count().label("games"),                                        
      )                                                                          
)
```

where

```
games = Game.query.filter(                                                  
      Game.started.isnot(None), Game.no_players.isnot(-1), Game.room == room  
  )
```

and Game an SQLAlchemy Model.

This results in data of the form `[(2020, 2, 20), (2020, 3, 65), (2020, 5, 3), ...]` with in this example no data for April 2020. The resulting bar chart would then display the data for all non-zero months, of course not giving a true display of reality.

I started looking into ways of extending the SQLAlchemy query to include zero-months by joining with a calendar table generated on the fly, but didn't really get very far. The underlying database is SQLite, by the way.

I have now "solved" the situation in Python as follows:

```
  data_raw = []                                                               
  for date in rrule.rrule(                                                    
          rrule.MONTHLY,                                                      
          dtstart=datetime.now() - relativedelta.relativedelta(months=11),    
          until=datetime.now(),                                               
  ):                                                                          
      for dbdata in data_db:                                                  
          if dbdata[0:2] == (date.year, date.month):                          
              data_raw.append(dbdata)                                         
              break                                                           
      else:                                                                   
          data_raw.append((date.year, date.month, 0))
```

which of course works, but leaves me with a bit of a sour taste in my mouth.

Since the datasets are so small this is more of a gold-plating question than a real performance issue, but I'd still like to see if there is an SQLAlchemy-only solution to this.

(I guess the graphing library (Chart.js in this case) could also have served to fill in the gaps perhaps, but I didn't look into that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a temporary table containing all of the year/month pairs (including the missing ones) and then LEFT JOIN that with your aggregation query (as a `.subquery()`):

```py
import datetime

from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Table,
    MetaData,
    Column,
    Integer,
    DateTime,
    desc,
    func,
    and_,
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, Session

engine = create_engine(
    "sqlite:///:memory:",
    future=True,
    echo=True,
)

Base = declarative_base()


class Game(Base):
    __tablename__ = "game"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    created = Column(DateTime)
    room = Column(Integer)
    no_players = Column(Integer)
    started = Column(DateTime)


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# create test data to query
with Session(engine, future=True) as session:
    session.add_all(
        [
            Game(
                created=datetime.datetime.now(),
                room=1,
                no_players=2,
                started=datetime.datetime.now(),
            ),
            Game(
                created=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1),
                room=1,
                no_players=2,
                started=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
            ),
            Game(
                created=datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                room=1,
                no_players=3,
                started=datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3),
            ),
        ]
    ),
    session.commit()

# define temporary table structure and data to insert
tmp_tbl_months = Table(
    "tmp_tbl_months",
    MetaData(),
    Column("year", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False),
    Column("month", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False),
    prefixes=["TEMPORARY"],
)

current_date = datetime.date.today()
loop_year = current_date.year
loop_month = current_date.month
tmp_data = []
num_months_to_report = 4
for i in range(num_months_to_report):
    tmp_data.append({"year": loop_year, "month": loop_month})
    if loop_month == 1:
        loop_month = 12
        loop_year -= 1
    else:
        loop_month -= 1
print(tmp_data)
# [
#  {'year': 2021, 'month': 3},
#  {'year': 2021, 'month': 2},
#  {'year': 2021, 'month': 1},
#  {'year': 2020, 'month': 12}
# ]

with engine.begin() as conn:
    tmp_tbl_months.create(conn)
    conn.execute(tmp_tbl_months.insert(), tmp_data)

    room = 1  # for testing
    games = session.query(Game).filter(
        Game.started.isnot(None), Game.no_players.isnot(-1), Game.room == room
    )
    aggregation = (
        games.group_by("year")
        .group_by("month")
        .order_by(desc("year"))
        .order_by(desc("month"))
        .limit(12)
        .with_entities(
            func.extract("year", Game.created).label("year"),
            func.extract("month", Game.created).label("month"),
            func.count().label("games"),
        )
        .subquery()
    )
    # temp_tbl_months LEFT JOIN aggregation (subquery)
    data_db = list(
        session.query()
        .select_from(tmp_tbl_months)
        .outerjoin(
            aggregation,
            and_(
                aggregation.c.year == tmp_tbl_months.c.year,
                aggregation.c.month == tmp_tbl_months.c.month,
            ),
        )
        .with_entities(
            tmp_tbl_months.c.year,
            tmp_tbl_months.c.month,
            func.coalesce(aggregation.c.games, 0),
        )
    )
    print(data_db)
    # [(2021, 3, 2), (2021, 2, 0), (2021, 1, 1), (2020, 12, 0)]
```

Comment: Waw, thanks a lot Gord! The `coalesce` in the end is nice.

While I can see this definitely works, I'm amazed by the amount of extra code it requires. I guess I was kind of hoping for generating this temporary table on the fly within a query or something.

I also looked in to the modifiers at https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html and was thinking of an SQLAlchemy way of accessing those.

In any case, thank you so much for obviously a lot of effort you put into getting yourself familiar with the case I presented!